# Is there a way to decrypt a stored procedure created with 'with encryption' in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure, encryption

Like the title says, is there a way to do that?

I've tried dbForge SQL Decryptor but I run into an error

> DBCC command 'DBInfo' not supported in this version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reference these tutorials:

1. [Simple Way to Decrypt SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/simple-way-to-decrypt-sql-server-stored-procedure).
2. [How to decrypt encrypted stored procedures](https://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-decrypt-encrypted-stored-procedures)

They all give us a way that using a procedure to decrypt the encrypted stroed procedures.

Example:

```
create  PROCEDURE sp_decrypt_sp (@objectName varchar(50))
AS
DECLARE  @OrigSpText1 nvarchar(4000),  @OrigSpText2 nvarchar(4000) , @OrigSpText3 nvarchar(4000), @resultsp nvarchar(4000)
declare  @i int , @t bigint

--get encrypted data
SET @OrigSpText1=(SELECT ctext FROM syscomments  WHERE id = object_id(@objectName))
SET @OrigSpText2='ALTER PROCEDURE '+ @objectName +' WITH ENCRYPTION AS '+REPLICATE('-', 3938)
EXECUTE (@OrigSpText2)

SET @OrigSpText3=(SELECT ctext FROM syscomments  WHERE id = object_id(@objectName))
SET @OrigSpText2='CREATE PROCEDURE '+ @objectName +' WITH ENCRYPTION AS '+REPLICATE('-', 4000-62)

--start counter
SET @i=1
--fill temporary variable
SET @resultsp = replicate(N'A', (datalength(@OrigSpText1) / 2))

--loop
WHILE @i<=datalength(@OrigSpText1)/2
BEGIN
--reverse encryption (XOR original+bogus+bogus encrypted)
SET @resultsp = stuff(@resultsp, @i, 1, NCHAR(UNICODE(substring(@OrigSpText1, @i, 1)) ^
                                (UNICODE(substring(@OrigSpText2, @i, 1)) ^
                                UNICODE(substring(@OrigSpText3, @i, 1)))))
 SET @i=@i+1
END
--drop original SP
EXECUTE ('drop PROCEDURE '+ @objectName)
--remove encryption
--preserve case
SET @resultsp=REPLACE((@resultsp),'WITH ENCRYPTION', '')
SET @resultsp=REPLACE((@resultsp),'With Encryption', '')
SET @resultsp=REPLACE((@resultsp),'with encryption', '')
IF CHARINDEX('WITH ENCRYPTION',UPPER(@resultsp) )>0 
  SET @resultsp=REPLACE(UPPER(@resultsp),'WITH ENCRYPTION', '')
--replace Stored procedure without enryption
execute( @resultsp)
GO
```

But for Azure:

Azure SQL Database does not support the WITH ENCRYPTION option object such as stored procedure.

Actually the stored procedure created `WITH ENCRYPTION` does not encrypt anything in Azure SQL database.

You could reference this [link](https://thomaslarock.com/2013/05/migrate-encrypted-procedures-azure-sql-database/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon,  Thank you but your link regarding Azure SQL may be out-dated. I've tested on Azure SQL myself and it does support 'WITH ENCRYPTION'
Please refer to the picture: https://pasteboard.co/IYSNVeW.png as you can see the 'TestEcryption' have a lock icon which means it is encrypted

Comment: @ChrisHoang That's a little strange, then does the decrypt work?

Comment: Your store proc does not work, the ctext column in table syscomments is null when the store proc is encrypted: https://pasteboard.co/IZkrTwU.png